# Can I fix an unsecure link in the html by adding an 's' and making the url https instead of http?

Tags: html, http

So I'm pretty familiar with html, css and java Script. And this moving company I work for wanted to know if I could fix this unsecured link in there html. I used Why no Padlock? and found that this link in the head tags is unsecure

https://www.whynopadlock.com/results/bcfb1f57-2f59-4787-8979-24beea641fe0

You can see that it's using http. Would making it https fix the issue or break the link?

Test result:

> A file with an insecure url of "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700,800&subset=latin,latin-ext" was loaded on line: 20 of your site.
>   This URL will need to be updated to use a secure URL for your padlock to return.

Comment: It was a very unclear question. I have never heard of the site you are linking to and would not click on the link until I realised it was a test result. I poste that result so it is now understandable you just need to use https for the font library

Answer (score 3):

I just had a look at your test results, it basically says that you include a google fonts stylesheet. Update that `<link` to use `https://` and you should be good.

Comment: Sweet thanks man. Also if you looked at the test results there's a warning that says       Your webserver is not forcing the use of SSL.
You may want to add a redirect to ensure a secure connection is used. More Info

Comment: Yea, it's just a warning though not a hard error. Still a good idea to fix that too.

Comment: They said they had an SSL certificate but the website says not secure? Is this what the error message is talking about or something else. I have no idea what to do here

Comment: I don't understand the question. The test report you shared is pretty clear on the problem

Answer (score -1):

Making it https:// will make your site inaccessible if you haven't obtain what is called SSL for your domain.

To fix that, obtain a SSL certificate for your website and the site will be served with https:// even when accessed with http://

Comment: How would it make the website inaccessible? If all this link is doing is bringing in fonts from google? If anything wouldn't changing that link to https just break that particular link? I fail to see how it would make the website inaccessible

Comment: My bad, I actually didn't see your test result before making the comment.